# Error 404 when setting up web app builder (developer edition) on computer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, node-js

I'm installing Web AppBuilder (Developer Edition) on my PC and running into an error.

I successfully connected to my local host and got to the page where I specify my Portal for ArcGIS URL. I have also set up my App ID in portal, registered, and provided that App ID in the browser server connection. I followed the steps laid out here: https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/getstarted.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F2CE6567CB854E4AB43F08EB64B3D7AE .

However, I am getting an error in an Apache Tomcat tab in my IE browser window that reads:

```
Page Not Found
Type: Status Report
Message: /webappbuilder/
Description: http.404/webappbuilder/
Portal for ArcGIS
```

Some additional details:

Not sure what this is all about--can anyone offer any guidance?

Node.js is installed and running. It appears to me that everything from the setup batch file initialized and works properly. My impression is that this is some kind of server connection/ portal account issue.

What I have tried:

Updated my existing App ID.

Setting the proxy for Web AppBuilder from node command node server.js [-proxy=value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a redirect issue and it is solved now.

I needed to set up my machine name (and port number) as an exception in the server token system. It was automatically redirecting to my organization's portal.

Comment: mark this as the correct answer pls